# Adding a Space or "0" at the end of the byte array java

Tags: java, arrays

How can i modify the existing byte array in such a way i can append the "space" or "0" if my condition met

```
for example :: 
last 2 byte Hex value if E0 in decimal is -32 
   byte1 [] = [48, 16, 6, 11, 43, 6, 1, 2, 1, 69, 1, 2, 1, 6, 9, 4, 1, -32]
last 1byte 101=e 48=0
    byte2[]=[48, 17, 6, 11, 43, 6, 1, 2, 1, 69, 1, 2, 1, 6, 9, 4, 2, 101, 48]
```

How can i know whether in the byte array last index is 2 byte the hex itself or 1 byte , if this is hex then i need to add a "0" or "space"  on the byte array

```
In precise : the last character need to be checked 
byte b = byte1[18]
check this whether it's one byte or 2 byte if it come as "e0" then 2 byte if it's come as "0" then modify the byte array to contain extra "0"
```

Comment: I'm afraid your question doesn't make much sense. Can you edit it to clarify, possibly have a colleague help?

Comment: In particular, it seems entirely unclear whether this is meant to be *binary* data (which it looks like) or *text* data (which is the only way in which the last two bytes representing 'e', '0' makes any sense)